# Jetty monitor WAR file and update when it changes

Tags: java, jetty

I have an embedded Jetty running with several different contexts, one of which is a WAR file. I want Jetty to redeploy the war file when it changes (probably because it was rebuilt by another process).

My current configuration:

```
    ContextHandlerCollection handler = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext("../../webapp/ROOT.war", "/");
    handler.setHandlers(new Handler[]{
            new WebAppContext("src/main/webapp", "/api"),
            webAppContext
    });

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(handler);
```

How do I change it to watch and redeploy the war file (`../../webapp/ROOT.war`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `WebAppContext` directly.

Use the `DeploymentManager` to find and deploy your webapps.

```java
    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    server.setHandler(contexts);

    DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
    deployer.setContexts(contexts);
    deployer.setContextAttribute(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
            ".*/servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$");

    WebAppProvider webapp_provider = new WebAppProvider();
    // The directory to monitor for WAR + XML files
    webapp_provider.setMonitoredDirName("/opt/jetty/webapps");
    webapp_provider.setScanInterval(1); // how often to scan
    webapp_provider.setExtractWars(true);
    webapp_provider.setTempDir(new File("/opt/jetty/work"));

    deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_provider);
    server.addBean(deployer);
```

Comment: This works for the `.war`, but not for the app mapped to `/api`. But it's a good start!

Comment: It will work for `/api` as well, you just have to setup an XML deployable in your monitored directory.   Said XML just configures a `WebAppContext` with a path to a directory, not a war file.